# In Angular, the body of a typed HttpResponse can be null. Why?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

The Angular `HttpClient` by default returns the body of a request parsed as JSON. For example,

```js
httpClient.get<Config>(url);
```

returns `Observable<Config>`: an observable of the expected `Config` object.

Similarly, to retrieve the full response (which includes e.g. the status code), you'd do the following:

```js
httpClient.get<Config>(url, { observe: "response" });
```

returns `Observable<HttpResponse<Config>>`: an observable of a full response object which has a body of `Config`.

In this case, I would expect the `body` of this `HttpResponse` to be of type `Config` (just like the body returned in the first case).

However, that type is `Config | null`. Why did the Angular maintainers choose different types for these — seemingly — identical cases of response bodies?

Comment: Because `HttpResponse<T>`'s `body` property is `T | null` - [_"...including a typed response body (which may be null if one was not returned)."_](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand, that's what the type says. I'm wondering why exactly the type is different in the second case. In theory, no response body could be returned in both cases — right? Why isn't the first case also of type `T | null`?

Comment: Because the default `observe?: 'body'` implementation returns `Observable<T>`. If you want to know why the maintainers made those specific decisions, you'd be better off posting on GitHub.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was indeed wondering why that decision was made. Their GitHub form actually directed me to Stackoverflow for this question. :-) Thanks for your time, though.

Comment: This happens too with `{ observe: 'event' }`. It's annoying how I have to tell TypeScript that "`HttpResponse.body` is not `null`" all the time.